# Need JSON data from given url using jquery for live streaming

Tags: php, jquery, json

This is the link from which I want to  get data:

```
http://xeuroasiantvx.api.channel.livestream.com/2.0/listplaylists.json?callback=listplaylists
```

Below is my code. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
$.getJSON('http://xeuroasiantvx.api.channel.livestream.com/2.0/listplaylists.json?callback=listplaylists').then(function(data) {
    alert('Your Json result is: ' + data.result); //you can comment this, i used it to debug
    result.innerText = data.result; //display the result in an HTML element
}, function(status) { //error detection....
    alert('Something went wrong.');
});
```

i  have also tried to use this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RamiSarieddine/HE2nY/1/)  but not working.

Comment: Firstly, that URL returns JSON, not JSONP. Secondly because you're making a request to an external domain you will be blocked by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). See the question I marked as duplicate for more information about the issue and potential workarounds.

Comment: What's happening now? Did you check for any console errors?

Comment: there are no errors in console. response is empty

Comment: you can try with ajax method. in ajax method  type will be GET and datatype will be jsonp.See the sample code here:http://jsfiddle.net/nu3v07hu/

Comment: @Yaseminçidem thanks dude i have already figured out the problem actually i was using dataType: json to get data from external url  but external url requires datatype: jsonp . now it's fixed :)